# Trigger different CSS keyframe animation based on scroll position (should I make an animation class?)

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have an animation that plays in the background of my website
that control different shapes. Each of them have an animation like so:

```
animation: animShape 50s linear infinite;
```

but the speed is different depending on  the shape.

animShape is:

```
animShape {
from {
transform: translateY(0px);
}
to {
transform: translateY(-2000px);
 }
}
```

I want to change the speed of each of my shapes (which are divs) based on the position of the scroll.

I was thinking about the best way to do this and I was hoping you could point me to the right direction?

Idea:
Have different animation classes that way I could use something like this:

```
$(document).on('scroll', '#section-trigger' , function(){              
$("#first-shape").removeClass('.first-animation-class');
$("#first-shape").addClass('.second-animation-class');})


$(document).on('scroll', '#another-section-trigger', function() {
$("#first-shape").removeClass('.second-animation-class');
$("#first-shape").addClass('first-animation-class');})

...
```

But I would have to do that for every shape div (since they all have different speeds) and I don't know if this is the correct way to go about it.

I could have JQuery handle all of the animations but I read that it can't access :after so I was hoping for a work around somebody knows?

Sorry for the formatting if it's wrong -- I get confused sometimes.
Thanks!

Comment: Not sure whether I've completely understood what you want, but how about changing the animation duration of each element depending on the scroll position?

Answer (score 0):

I prepared an animation that reacts with scrolling and used a timer to synchronize the execution and end of the animation.

> Just make sure that each animation you put is in line with the timer.
> For example, I put an animation 2 seconds and twice, that is, it takes
> 4 seconds to run once.

*Of course, with a little change in the same structure, you can run any animation*

```js
let timer;
var timerCount = 0;
MyTimer();
var element1 = document.getElementById("myDIV1");
var element2 = document.getElementById("myDIV2");
function doSomething() {
  
  if(!element1.classList.contains('anim1'))
      element1.classList.add("anim1");

  if(!element2.classList.contains('anim2')) 
      element2.classList.add("anim2");     
}


function MyTimer()
{
    timerCount = timerCount + 1;
    if(timerCount >= 5)
    {
     
      if(element1.classList.contains('anim1'))
         element1.classList.remove("anim1");
      if(element2.classList.contains('anim2'))
         element2.classList.remove("anim2");
         
       timerCount = 0;
    }
    timer = setTimeout(MyTimer, 1000);
}


document.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
 doSomething();
});
```

```css
body{
   height:2500px;
}
.shape1{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  float:left;

}
.shape2{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  float:right;
}
.wrapper{
   width;100%;
   border:1px solid #ddd;
   padding:20px;
   margin:150px 20px;
   height:150px;
}
.anim1 {
  animation-name: example1;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: 2;
  animation-direction: alternate;  
}

.anim2 {
  animation-name: example2;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: 2;
  animation-direction: alternate;  
}

@keyframes example1 {
  0%   {background-color:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
  25%  {background-color:yellow; left:100px; top:0px;}
  50%  {background-color:blue; left:100px; top:100px;}
  75%  {background-color:green; left:0px; top:100px;}
  100% {background-color:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
}

@keyframes example2 {
  0%   {background-color:red; right:0px; top:0px;}
  25%  {background-color:yellow; right:100px; top:0px;}
  50%  {background-color:blue; right:100px; top:100px;}
  75%  {background-color:green; right:0px; top:100px;}
  100% {background-color:red; right:0px; top:0px;}
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="myDIV1" class="shape1"></div>
    <div id="myDIV2" class="shape2"></div>
</div>
```